# RxSwift: Chain Completable to Observable

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I'd like to chain a Completable to an observable element. After calling *flatMap*, onCompleted and onError callbacks don't seem to be called on subscription.

```
var user = PublishRelay<User>()

func fetchUserInformation(_ userId: String) -> Completable {
    return Completable.create { observer in
        apiService.fetchInformation(for: userId, completion: { response in
            if let name = response?.name {
                user.accept(User(name: name))
                observer(.completed)
            } else {
                observer(.error(ServiceError.userInformation))
            }
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

login()
.flatMap{ userId in fetchUserInformation(userId) }
.subscribe(
    onCompleted: {
        print("Success!") // Not being called at all
    },
    onError: { error in
        print(error)  // Not being called at all
    }
).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Although *fetchUserInformation* and *observer(.completed)* are being called and user information is being successfully fetched, I won't be able to catch *onCompleted* on subscription (only when preceded by *flatMap*).

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

> Already tried *.materialized()* just after the *flatMap* call in order to get an
>
> ```
>     Observable<Event<Never>>
> ```
>
> rather than a
>
> ```
>     Observable<Never>
> ```
>
> It doesn't work either.

Comment: Don't use `Completable` if it doesn't fit your needs... Also, `onCompleted` is not called because while your inner observable (`fetchUserInformation`) completes, this does not complete your outer observable: on next login value, it will trigger again `fetchUserInformation`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The correct solution would be using the ‘andThen’ operator.

```
someCompletable
   .andThen(someObservable)
```

**Edit**:
Just read the rest of your code - I'm not sure why you use a `Completable` at all since it seems you are actually returning some element from that stream.

You'll probably want to use a `Single` or Plain-ol' observable to relay that value without using an external Relay.

Comment: Would appreciate knowing what the -1 was for :)

Answer (score 7):

I think that you can do something like this:

```
login()
    .flatMap{ userId -> Observable<Void> in
        return fetchUserInformation(userId).andThen(.just(Void()))
    }.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        ...
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't convert Completable to Observable since the later omits values while Completable does not.

I guess flatMap is returning Observables from Login and then you convert it to Completables and that's why it fails